# SonarScanner in Docker cannot find java

Tags: java, docker, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate SonarQube into my CI process. I tried to install SonarScanner in Docker, but it appears it cannot find java tho it can be run

**Dockerfile**

```
# Docker, AWS CLI, Terraform, NodeJS
FROM docker:18-dind
RUN echo "1"
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk11 --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
RUN apk update
RUN apk add awscli nodejs nodejs-npm wget unzip jq openjdk11
RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.13/terraform_0.11.13_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_0.11.13_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/local/bin
RUN npm i -g sequelize sequelize-cli mysql2
RUN wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873.zip
RUN unzip sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873.zip
RUN ls sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873
ENV PATH="/sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/bin:${PATH}"
RUN which java
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin
RUN echo $PATH
RUN java --version
RUN ls /sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/bin
RUN sonar-scanner --help
```

**The logs**

```
Step 15/20 : RUN which java
 ---> Running in 96b487f5b44f
/usr/bin/java
Removing intermediate container 96b487f5b44f
 ---> 5026de427a57
Step 16/20 : ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin
 ---> Running in 4d7eee221e41
Removing intermediate container 4d7eee221e41
 ---> 76b9a8b9d803
Step 17/20 : RUN echo $PATH
 ---> Running in 4278142f7153
/sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Removing intermediate container 4278142f7153
 ---> c3d528bdaa7e
Step 18/20 : RUN java --version
 ---> Running in 7df7e2d8a441
openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-alpine-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-alpine-r0, mixed mode)
Removing intermediate container 7df7e2d8a441
 ---> 0f7162dae25d
Step 19/20 : RUN ls /sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/bin
 ---> Running in b7efb86cd86e
sonar-scanner
sonar-scanner-debug
sonar-scanner-debug.bat
sonar-scanner.bat
Removing intermediate container b7efb86cd86e
 ---> ff640a70876f
Step 20/20 : RUN sonar-scanner --help
 ---> Running in 9164ac2e8369
Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
The command '/bin/sh -c sonar-scanner --help' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Notice `which java` gives `/usr/bin/java`. So I set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin`. `java` can run. But `sonar-scanner` cannot appear to find `java` ... why is that?

Comment: `/usr/bin` isn't a proper JAVA_HOME, though, it should be the actual folder where alpine added it. Note: you're adding openjdk11 twice and you should consider collapsing your Docker RUN commands where necessary

Comment: I assume that many of those commands are for debugging the current issue - but I would say that commands add a layer and those commands that just print things out add layers too; they’ll bloat your image for no benefit. I would suggest separating _building_ your container from _testing_ it - simply `docker run` the created image to execute your diagnostic commands!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `JAVA_HOME` ENV according to version, as mentioned @cricket_007 the path in alpine for JDK is `/usr/lib/jvm/{VERSION}`

```
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"  
RUN echo $PATH
```

run docker

```
docker run --privileged -it --rm sonar-s sonar-scanner --version
```

output

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.2.0.1873
INFO: Java 11.0.5 Alpine (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.14.70-67.55.amzn1.x86_64 amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

This Dockerfile worked for me on .Net :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes openjdk-11-jre
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
RUN export ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
RUN export ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}" 
RUN echo $PATH
RUN export ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
RUN echo $PATH
```

I had to run the image and exec into it to find the exact version ( **java-11-openjdk-amd6** in my case)